# MVC ModelStatus error is not displaying in view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Here is my action:

```
public virtual ActionResult DeleteClass(int id)
    {
           var Model = service.AllClasses();
            MergeModelState(service.Exceptions);  // Please see below description
            return RedirectToAction("Index",Classes);
        }
```

**Edit**
My view code is here:

```
@using Scripts = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts
@model List<Demo.CustomTypes.Class>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Location</td>
                        <td>Teacher</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var itm in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(@itm.Name,MVC.CodeTest.Students().AddRouteValue("id",@itm.ClassID))</td>
                            <td>@itm.Location</td>
                            <td>@itm.Teacher</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit",MVC.CodeTest.EditClass().AddRouteValue("id",itm.ClassID))
                                <br/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete",MVC.CodeTest.DeleteClass().AddRouteValue("id",itm.ClassID))
                                <br/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                </table>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Add",MVC.CodeTest.AddClass())
                                <br/>

                </div>

            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

In action I m using MergeModelState to add errors (string key, string message) and then I want to display it in view but in view I m not getting any error / validation message. In Immidiate Windows I can see in ModelState errors are added. Please help.

**Edit 2:**

Here is my method which is adding errors in ModelState. It is in BaseController class and my controller is inharting this class.

```
public class BaseContoller : Controller
    {
        public void MergeModelState(List<ExceptionPairs> exceptions )
        {
            foreach (var exception in exceptions)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, exception.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `@Html.ValidationSummary()` inside a form element?

Comment: I hope you have included the necessary .js files ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no it is not, that is the all code of view which I show there.

Comment: @amarduplantier, which .js need to be included, sorry have not included any ?

Answer (score 2):

You must have `@Html.ValidationSummary()` inside a form element for it to display. Refer the following snippet from the MVC source code (No form, no messages!)

```
private static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, string tag)
{
  string modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName) && formContext == null)
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have added form tag in my view but it is still not showing. Can you have a look at my updated view code and guide please.

Comment: in my view I have @@using Scripts = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts at top, other then that do i need to add jquery or any other js file ? Sorry i m new and dont know much about basics.

Comment: By using `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, you are excluding property errors so try without the parameter (or use `false`). You don't need the `@using Scripts = System....`,  and you only need the jquery files (validate and validate.unobtrusive) for client side validation

Comment: did all things you mentioned but no luck. Just a question please. In my action I m getting Id and not Model. Inside Action I create model, then I add errors in ModelState. Can It be a reason ?

Comment: dont mean to take much of your time but I have added my method which is adding errors in ModelState as well. Will highly appriciate if you please can review it.

Comment: I cant comment on you code for adding errors, but I suggest you test that the errors display correctly by faking an error e.g. `public ActionResult YourAction(...){...ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Im an error");...return View(..)}`. You could also add `var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);` after the fake error and put a breakpoint to inspect the error.

Comment: I'm curious why you are outputting exceptions this way. `ModelStateErrors` are to intended to display validation errors. The normal method for handling exceptions to to return a custom error page. For example, on you base controller you can add the `HandleErrorAttribute` e.g. `[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ViewDeniedException), View = "ViewDeniedError")]`. I also notice that you are using this on a 'read only' view so having a `form` element does not see appropriate. If you really want to show exceptions this way, consider a view model with a `List<string> Errors get; set;}` property

Comment: you are right, this view has a table with two button columns (edit and delete). On delete button some business validations are done and if any of them failed I need to show message. My controller is getting List of error and service layer and merging it to ModelState. As I need to show error on same page that is why I used this technique.

Answer (score 0):

model error shows only to the view of current controller.
i.e- we cant use `return RedirectToAction("Index",Classes);`

you must use `return view (model);` 
then only view shows error in model.